# How to use custom webpack configuration in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, webpack, ionic4

How can I extend the Default Webpack config and use a custom one?

I'm trying to use a package that requires some extra webpack configuration and I'm not sure how to do this. Ever since Angular 6, it's been kind of complicated to do this. Who knows how?

I've tried following some tutorial around:

1. https://javascripttuts.com/using-a-custom-webpack-configuration-in-an-ionic-4-application/
2. https://alligator.io/angular/custom-webpack-config/

Which led me to

```
@angular-builders/dev-server:generic
```

and

```
@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser
```

I, however, ran into an error whenever I try to build, serve.

```
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path ".builders['browser']" should have required property 'class'.
```

Comment: what exactly you need to perform btw? i was recently doing the same (finding webpack for ng7) but then found how hooks are now done in ionic4 via ionic.config.json and for my operations  to modify certain files this went real smooth

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom webpack configuration for Ionic 4/Angular as follows.

Create a custom Webpack configuration file in the root of your project:

```
$ touch custom.webpack.config.js
```

Open the `custom.webpack.config.js` file and add the following code:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
console.log('The custom config is used');
```

Next, head back to your terminal and install npm package(s).

```bash
$ npm install --save @angular-builders/custom-webpack
```

If using Angular version <8, also install:

```bash
$ npm install --save @angular-builders/dev-server
```

The @angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server builder makes use of the custom webpack builder to get webpack configuration.

Unlike the default @angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server it doesn't use@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser configuration to run the development server. If you use @angular-builders/dev-server:generic along with @angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser, ng serve will run with custom configuration provided in the latter.

Now, open the angular.json file, locate the projects -> app -> architect -> build -> builder entry and swap @angular-devkit/build-angular:browser with @angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser.

Next, under the options object, add "customWebpackConfig": {"path": "./custom.webpack.config.js"}:

```
  "projects": {
    "app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./custom.webpack.config.js"
            },
```

Next, for Angular versions <8, change the builder property under the serve property to @angular-builders/dev-server:generic:

```
  "projects": {
    "app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {},
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/dev-server:generic",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          },
```

For Angular 8+, change the builder property under the serve property to @angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server:

```
  "projects": {
    "app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {},
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          },
```

Now, if you serve your application again, the custom Webpack configuration will be used and you should see The custom config is used message displayed in your terminal.

You can find a [tutorial with a practical example here](https://www.techiediaries.com/ionic-angular-typeorm-custom-webpack-configuration/)

Comment: From Angular 8+ you do not have to install `@angular-builders/dev-server` and instead of `@angular-builders/dev-server:generic` you have to put `@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server` to the `serve` `bulder` config.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment, it will be better if you add your package.json and angular.json code.Try downgrading your "@angular-devkit/build-angular" package to ^0.12.X, if you are running v6 of "@angular-builders/custom-webpack".

Answer (score 0):

[Refer if you got doubt](https://www.javascripttuts.com/using-a-custom-webpack-configuration-in-an-ionic-4-application/)

**TypeORM from npm:**

```
$ cd ionic-crm
$ npm install typeorm --save
```

As the time of this writing, `typeorm v0.2.16` will be installed.

Next, install `Node.js` types:

```
$ npm install @types/node --save-dev
```

Since we'll be doing testing in the browser we also need to install `sql.js`:

```
$ npm install sql.js --save
```

As the time of this writing, `sql.js v0.5.0` will be installed.

Next, open the `tsconfig.json` file and add `"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]` under compilerOptions if it's not already there.

Next, open the src/tsconfig.app.json and change accordingly:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["node"],
    "paths": {
      "typeorm": ["node_modules/typeorm/browser"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Adding a Custom Webpack Configuration
Next, create a custom Webpack configuration file in the root of your project:

```
$ touch custom.webpack.config.js
```

Open the `custom.webpack.config.js` file and add the following code:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
console.log('The custom config is used');
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            'window.SQL': 'sql.js/js/sql.js'
        }),
        new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/typeorm$/, function (result) {
            result.request = result.request.replace(/typeorm/, "typeorm/browser");
        })
    ],
    node: {
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty',
        tls: 'empty'
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: false
    }
};
```

Next, head back to your terminal and install the @angular-builders/custom-webpack and @angular-builders/dev-server packages from npm:

```
$ npm install --save @angular-builders/custom-webpack
$ npm install --save @angular-builders/dev-server
```

The `@angular-builders/custom-webpack v7.4.3` and `*@angular-builders/dev-server v7.3.1 *` packages will be installed.

The `@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server` builder makes use of the custom webpack builder to get webpack configuration. Unlike the default @angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server it doesn't use@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser configuration to run the development server. If you use @angular-builders/dev-server:generic along with @angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser, ng serve will run with custom configuration provided in the latter.

Now, open the `angular.json` file, locate the `projects -> app -> architect -> build -> builder` entry and swap @angular-devkit/build-angular:browser with `@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser.`

Next, under the options object, add

```
"customWebpackConfig": {"path": "./custom.webpack.config.js"}:

  "projects": {
    "app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./custom.webpack.config.js"
            },
```

Next, change the builder property under the serve property to @angular-builders/dev-server:generic:

```
 "projects": {
    "app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {},
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/dev-server:generic",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          },
```

Now, if you serve your application again, the custom Webpack configuration will be used and you should see The custom config is used message displayed in your terminal.

Comment: Starting on Angular v8, the value for the builder option under the serve object should be `@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server` instead of `@angular-builders/dev-server:generic`, check this link to the deprecation announcement: https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/blob/master/MIGRATION.MD